# Ruby: stringA.gsub(/\s+/, '') versus stringA.strip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say

```
string = "Johnny be good! And smile   :-) "
```

Is there a difference between

```
string.gsub(/\s+/, '')
```

and

```
string.strip
```

?

If so, what is it?

Comment: Have you ever tested your code? The difference is huge.

Comment: not yet; am sensing it is and wanted to first conceptually understand. Been reading the ruby doc and didn't catch the difference in the samples there (sorry for ignorance, am beginner).

Comment: `String#strip` only removes leading and trailing blank characters (spaces, tabs and line feeds), while `gsub(/\s+/, '')` removes all blank characters.

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter open IRB, type it in. That's faster than writing a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strip` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, using `gsub` in the way that you outline in your question will remove all whitespace from the string.

```
irb(main):004:0* " hello ".strip
=> "hello"
irb(main):005:0> " h e l l o ".strip
=> "h e l l o"
irb(main):006:0> " hello ".gsub(/\s+/, '')
=> "hello"
irb(main):007:0> " h e l l o ".gsub(/\s+/, '')
=> "hello"
```

Comment: ah ok so only at beginning and end of string. I was thinking/understanding leading/trailing to each character